# How to return a splat from a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I wanted to create a method for array's to get a splat of the array in return. Is this possible to do in Ruby?

For example here's my current code:

```
Array.module_eval do
  def to_args
    return *self
  end
end
```

I expect `[1,2,3].to_args` to return `1,2,3` but it ends up returning `[1,2,3]`

Comment: If you explained how you'd like to use this method your question might be clearer.

Comment: `1,2,3` is not a valid value in ruby, so it's not clear what you actually want. A string?

Comment: All Ruby methods return one object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot return a "splat" from Ruby. But you can return an array and then splat it yourself:

```
def args
  [1, 2, 3]
end
x, y, z = args 
# x == 1
# y == 2
# z == 3

x, *y = args
# x == 1
# y == [2, 3]
```

Of course, this works on any array, so really there is no need for monkey patching a `to_args` method into `Array` - it's all about how the calling concern is using the splat operator:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
x, y, z = arr
x, *y = arr
*x, y = arr
```

Same mechanism works with block arguments:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr.tap {|x, *y| y == [2, 3]}
```

Even more advanced usage:

```
arr = [1, [2, 3]]
x, (y, z) = arr
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept that clarifies this for me is that although you can *simulate* the return of multiple values in Ruby, a method can really return only 1 object, so that simulation bundles up the multiple values in an Array.

The array is returned, and you can then deconstruct it, as you can any array.

```
def foo
  [1, 2]
end

one, two = foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.  What it looks like you're trying to do (the question doesn't give usage examples) is to force multiple return values.  However, returning the splatted array `self` may do exactly what you need, as long as you're properly handling multiple return values on the calling side of the equation.

Consider these examples:

```
first, *rest = [1, 2, 3]        # first = 1, rest = [2, 3]
*rest, last = [1, 2, 3]         # rest = [1, 2], last = 3
first, *rest, last = [1, 2, 3]  # first = 1, rest = [2], last = 3
```

Other than this, I can't actually see any way to capture or pass along multiple values like you're suggesting.  I think the answer for your question, if I understand it correctly, is all in the caller's usage.